# Defining conditional Notation rules

Tags: linux, custom-notation

I am trying to define a notation rule so that for selected symbols subsripts will be equivalent to function parameters.
My understanding of the docs suggests the following

```
<< Notation`

sub[f_] := Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(Subscript[\(f, \(\ x_\)\)]\)]
     \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[\(f[x_]\)]]
```

The idea is to be able to do the following

```
sub[P]
Subscript[P, i] := F[i]
Subscript[P, a]
```

and have Mathematica treat it the same as

```
P[i] := F[i]
P[a]
```

But `Subscript[Q, i]` should remain as a just a subscript expression

Mathematica throws the following  error on the definition of `sub`:

```
Notation::expatnf: Pattern 'x' appearing in the external representation 'Notation`Private`identityForm[RowBox[{OverBar,[,x_,]}]]' cannot be filled since 'x' does not appear in the internal representation 'Notation`Private`identityForm[RowBox[{mean,[,x,]}]]'. >>
```

I would like to understand what the problem is and fix it. I am also interest in alternative approaches to achieving the same effect. I am also interested finding more documantation for the Notation package then is in the standard documentation, particularly extended examples and conceptual overviews.

** EDIT

Here is what I get with Leonid's approach

```
In[1]:=
Remove[P, F]
Clear[Subscript, MakeExpression, makeExpression]; 
MakeExpression[expr_, form_] := 
   With[{result = makeExpression[expr, form]}, 
    result /; Head[result] === HoldComplete]; 
ClearAll[sub]; 
sub[f_] := With[{boxed = MakeBoxes[f]}, 
    makeExpression[RowBox[{"Subscript", "[", 
        RowBox[{boxed, ",", arg_}], "]"}], form_] := 
     MakeExpression[RowBox[{boxed, "[", arg, "]"}], form]]; 

In[6]:= sub[P]

In[7]:= Subscript[P, i]:= F[i]
```

I would really prefer the rule to be interpreted as `P[i] := F[i]`. I want the subscripts to be purely cosmetic. On my system the `Subscript[P, i]` on the LHS does not get interpreted that way:

```
In[8]:= DownValues[Subscript]

Out[8]= {HoldPattern[Subscript[P, i]] :> F[i]}

In[9]:= DownValues[P]

Out[9]= {}
```

The following shows that the parsing of the notation works, but I actually want the rendering to reverse the parsing when in StandardForm.

```
In[10]:= Subscript[P, a]

Out[10]= P[a]
```

However the `:=` definition does not work as kick in:

```
In[11]:= Subscript[P, i]

Out[11]= P[i]
```

Also the parsing code only works on code that was entered after the notation related code was evaluated. Expressions entered before the notation code was evaluated are not effected, even after restarting Mathematica.
The following expression is in the same notebook but was in there from before Leonids answer and is identical to the first expression above:

```
In[12]:= Subscript[P, a]

Out[12]= Subscript[P, a]
```

In other words the notebook is somehow remembering which expressions were entered before the notation code and which were entered after even across Mathematica restarts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the problems of the `` Notation` `` package is that it is rather heavy and opaque, while what it actually does is rather simple. I suggest a very light-weight substitute for your case:

```
Clear[MakeExpression,makeExpression];
MakeExpression[expr_,form_]:=
    With[{result=makeExpression[expr,form]},
        result /; Head[result]===HoldComplete
    ];

ClearAll[sub];
sub[f_]:=
    With[{boxed=MakeBoxes[f]},
        makeExpression[
            RowBox[{"Subscript","[",RowBox[{boxed,",",arg_}],"]"}],form_
        ]:=
            MakeExpression[RowBox[{boxed,"[",arg,"]"}],form];

        makeExpression[SubscriptBox[boxed, arg_], form_] :=
            MakeExpression[RowBox[{boxed, "[", arg, "]"}], form];
    ];
```

Now, you use this as you would in your question:

```
sub[P]
Subscript[P, i] := F[i]
Subscript[P, a]

(* P[a] *)

Subscript[P, i]

(* F[i] *)
```

while for a general subscript with a different symbol you get the same as before:

```
Subscript[Q, i]

(* Subscript[Q, i] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I put the initial definitions. Simply adding them at the top of the notebook and evaluating the notebook does not seem to be doing this.

Comment: @DanielMahler Just tested once again on a fresh kernel, M9.0.0, Mac OS X, placed the definitions in a cell and evaluated in a newly created notebook. The test usage is in a different cell. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: @All ***would be nice if those reading my answer above, could confirm*** whether or not this works for them, and on which platforms.

Comment: Works on Win7/M9.0.1

Comment: @Ymareth Thanks for checking!

Comment: @DanielMahler Make sure you try on a fresh kernel. If you have ``Notation` `` loaded, or otherwise a non-fresh kernel, that may interfere.

Comment: I am restarting the kernel and then doing Evaluate Notebook. BTW is there a better way to get clean up your environment than restarting?

Comment: @DanielMahler First, I would not do Evaluate Notebook: why don't you just evaluate that cell with the definitions, and then try the usage examples. Re: clean up - you can do `ClearAll["Global`*"]` or `Remove["Global`*"]`. This does not guarantee that you cleaned up everything, but should be good enough for many cases. I personally usually restart the kernel though, since this is the only way to guarantee that you start with a fresh session.

Comment: @DanielMahler The comment escaping played a bad joke on me, I meant ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` and ``Remove["Global`*"]``.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I have added details of what happens. I was in a fresh kernel and evaluating the cells individually.

Comment: @DanielMahler This is not what I am getting: once I evaluate `DownValues[Subscript]`, I get `{}`, while `DownValues[P]` gives me `{HoldPattern[P[i]] :> F[i]}`. What version are you using and on what platform?

Comment: @DanielMahler I just asked some folks in chat to double-check, their result agrees with mine. It looks like something is wrong on your system. You can join the chat room, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14635271#14635271), to discuss - but I am not going to be around for much longer tonight.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I am using a Linux 64 bit 9.0.1.0 trial version

Comment: @DanielMahler You may try to ask someone in the chat room to test on Linux - I am on Mac OS X. But I'd be very surprised if Linux version would behave in this way. As to your question about how the notebook remembers things: the question is what you used for your input: `FullForm` or typeset expression. If you entered like `Subscript[P, i]`, it should work after you execute my code. If you used typesetting (via palette of otherwise), then the box representation is different (the head is then `SubscriptBox`, and my code does not catch that - which would explain it).

Comment: Leonid, I get your answer but I think the cause for confusion is because @DanielMahler is probably using the 2D subscript notation whereas `makeExpression` handles the fullform. Daniel, could you change the definition of `sub` to `ClearAll[sub];
sub[f_] := With[{boxed = MakeBoxes[f]}, 
   makeExpression[SubscriptBox[boxed, arg_], form_] := MakeExpression[RowBox[{boxed, "[", arg, "]"}], form]];` and see if it does what you want?

Comment: @rm-rf I was 20 secs faster :)

Comment: @rm-rf But thanks a bunch, I appreciate that you took the time to look into this.

Comment: @DanielMahler I have edited my answer and added another definition to my code, which should be able to catch the case of using the typeset form: `makeExpression[SubscriptBox[boxed, arg_], form_] :=MakeExpression[RowBox[{boxed, "[", arg, "]"}], form];`. Try the new one and see if it works for you.

Comment: @DanielMahler By the way, it is exactly this sort of problems which tell me that mixing notation and programming / interactive work is generally a bad idea. I never do it, and neither do most of the experienced users I know. If you need to render things nicely for presentation, it is best done as a separate module and separate step in your workflow (one of the final ones).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin No problem! I'll take care of the crumbs here and there to free you some time to finish that book of yours ;)

Comment: @rm-rf Ironically, my initial code was using `SubscriptBox`, but because I was entering in the `FullForm`, it did not work for me, and I later changed that to `RowBox[...]`. And because that was my starting point, it didn't occur to me that that branch should be kept, until the last moment.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix up your `sub` definition to do what you want:

```
sub[f_Symbol] := With[{n = SymbolName[f]},
    Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper @ SubscriptBox[n, "x_"] ⟺ ParsedBoxWrapper @ RowBox[{n, "[", "x_", "]"}]]
]
```

For your example:

```
Clear[P]
Subscript[P, i_] := F[i]
P[a]
```

> F[a]

The [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) of `P` have been defined as desired:

```
DownValues[P] //InputForm
```

> {HoldPattern[P[i_]] :> F[i]}